# Why do I need to copy class instances but not other object types in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a little confused about when I need to explicitly copy an object in Python in order to make changes without altering the original. The [Python doc page](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html) doesn't have too much detail, and simply says that "assignment statements do not create copies".

Example 1:

```
>>> a = 4
>>> b = a
>>> b += 1
>>> print(b)
>>> print(a)

# Results are what you'd "expect" them to be:
5
4
```

Example 2:

```
>>> class Test():
>>>     def __init__(self, x):
>>>         self.x = x
>>> 
>>> A = Test(4)
>>> B = A
>>> B.x += 1
>>> print(B.x)
>>> print(A.x)

# Unexpected results because B isn't actually a copy of A:
5
5
```

### Why do the two examples behave differently?

Edit: In order to get Example 2 to work, I basically did the following. I'm asking why this isn't necessary for Example 1:

```
>>> import copy
>>> A = Test(4)
>>> B = copy.copy(A)
>>> B.x += 1
>>> print(B.x)
>>> print(A.x)
```

Comment: in example 1, `b+=1` change `b`'s value to `b+1`, which is a new object. `a` still ref to `4`. in example 2, `a` and `b` both ref `Test`, and you change `Test.x` to `5`. `a` and `b` don't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = 4
b = a
```

..would mean "make `b` refer to whatever `a` refers to". That would be 4 in this case. Since integers are [*immutable*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Data_Types#Mutable_vs_Immutable_Objects), changing `b` by doing `b += 1` would make it point to a different object

Check their [ids](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=id#id):

```
a = 4
b = a

print(id(a)) # Same id
print(id(b)) # Same id

b = 123

print(id(b)) # Different id
```

Same thing happens with instances A and B when B is not a `.copy()`.

> **id**(object)
>
> Return the “identity” of an object.

---

An interesting example with *mutable* objects:

```
l = [1, 2]
k = l

print(id(l)) # Same id
print(id(k)) # Same id

k.append(3)

print(id(k)) # Same id
print(l, k)  # Prints [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
```

`append()` modifies the object both `k` and `l` refer to. It doesn't assign `k` to a different object.

As mentioned by @blcckngth:

```
k = k + [3]

print(id(k)) # Different id ..
print(l, k)  # ..prints [1, 2] [1, 2, 3]
```

while `k += [3]` would result in reference to the same object.

Comment: You might add on to your second example by doing `k += [4]` and `k = k + [5]`.

Answer (score 2):

In your example 1, you write `b += 1`. That's the same thing as writing `b = b + 1`. That uses the `=` operator to *assign a value to `b`*. You're just changing the value that the name `b` refers to. In example 2, you're changing an *attribute* of the object that both names (`A` and `B`) refer to. They still both refer to the same object in memory, so changing the `.x` attribute of that object changes both `B.x` and `A.x`.

Comment: "That's the same thing as writing `b = b + 1`" - not quite. Immutable objects like ints implement it that way, but for something like a list, `l += [thing]` is quite different from `l = l + [thing]`.