# Issue when moving an object inside a list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-turtle

This is just a short part of my code (I'm new with python). The goal is to move all of the elements one position forward.

```
from turtle import  Turtle

turtles = []

for i in range(4):
    t = Turtle()
    t.color("white")
    t.setx(i*-20)
    turtles.append(t)

for i in range(len(turtles)-1, 0, -1):
    print(f"Element in position {i} with xcor {turtles[i].xcor()} will have the xcor {turtles[i-1].xcor()}")
    turtles[i] = turtles[i-1]

turtles[0].forward(20)
print(" After modification of element in position 0")
print(f"Element in position 0 has xcor = {turtles[0].xcor()}")
print(f"Element in position 1 has xcor = {turtles[1].xcor()}")
```

However, I do not understand why the objects in positions 0 and 1 were modified at the same time.

```
Element in position 3 with xcor -60 will have the xcor -40
Element in position 2 with xcor -40 will have the xcor -20
Element in position 1 with xcor -20 will have the xcor 0
 After modification of element in position 0
Element in position 0 has xcor = 20.0
Element in position 1 has xcor = 20.0
```

I was waiting to see the xcor = 0 for element in position 1.

Comment: `turtles[1] is turtles[0]`. Why did you expect them to be independent?

Comment: In your own words, when you do the `turtles[i] = turtles[i-1]` loop, what do you expect to happen to the list? In particular, what do you expect `turtles[0]` to be? What do you expect `turtles[1]` to be? Do you expect those to be the same `Turtle`, or merely separate `Turtle`s that are equal or copied in some way? Are you under the impression that `turtles[i] = turtles[i-1]` creates a copy? It does not.

Comment: You might want to read [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder, [this part](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html#h_assignment) in particular: *"Fact: Assignment never copies data"*. Although in your case you're not assigning to a name, but an element of a list.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191405/why-do-i-need-to-copy-class-instances-but-not-other-object-types-in-python help? There are many other previous questions I could point at, but none seems like *quite* the right duplicate.

Comment: Ok thank for your replay. I thought the loop was creating a copy of the object before moving it into the new position. But with the link you provided before everything is clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`turtles[1]` and `turtles[0]` are the same object. In other words, `turtles[1] is turtles[0]`.

To copy a `Turtle`, use [`.clone()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.clone), for example, here:

```
turtles[i] = turtles[i-1].clone()
```

Comment: Ok thank for your replay. I thought the loop was creating a copy of the object before moving it into the new position. But with the link you provided before everything is clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Although @wjandrea's approach will work, I'd say it's the wrong thing to do.  Turtles, unless the screen is reset or turtle is exited, are effectively global.  Cloning each of them for every movement will create lots of turtles that hang around.  Instead, I'd fix your `list` logic:

```
from turtle import Turtle

turtles = []

for i in range(4):
    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.setx(i * -20)

    turtles.append(turtle)

print("Before modification of element in position 0")
for i, turtle in enumerate(turtles):
    print(f"turtles[{i}] has xcor = {turtle.xcor()} [{id(turtle)}]")

# Move list forward

turtle = turtles.pop()
turtle.setx(turtles[0].xcor() + 20)
turtles.insert(0, turtle)

print("\nAfter modification of element in position 0")
for i, turtle in enumerate(turtles):
    print(f"turtles[{i}] has xcor = {turtle.xcor()} [{id(turtle)}]")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
Before modification of element in position 0
turtles[0] has xcor = 0 [4543646496]
turtles[1] has xcor = -20 [4557792880]
turtles[2] has xcor = -40 [4557793840]
turtles[3] has xcor = -60 [4557795280]

After modification of element in position 0
turtles[0] has xcor = 20 [4557795280]
turtles[1] has xcor = 0 [4543646496]
turtles[2] has xcor = -20 [4557792880]
turtles[3] has xcor = -40 [4557793840]
>
```

Comment: Ah yeah, I didn't even think of that! Thanks!

Comment: If you want a data structure that supports easy rotation, you could use a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque), like `turtles.rotate(); turtles[0].setx(turtles[1].xcor() + 20)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarifications @cdlane